# Should I have the build file of a project along with the source code?

Tags: build

I think that it would be a good idea to have a track of the build file of a project. But, I've read that build files should not be public, since they can contain "sensible" information.

Is recommendable to have the build file in the same repository of the source code? Even if the repo is public? If it is not recommendable, would I have to have an independent repo for each project only for the build file?

Edit: the projects would be plugins for Moodle. And, I've never used build systems before, as I guess you have already deduced.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention what kind of build system you're using. Nevertheless, having the build file along the project source has advantages:

- The build file is versioned the same way the source code is
- You don't have to keep track of which build file belongs to which project

You shouldn't have any sensible information within a build file - most systems allow you do have encrypted authentication information in a build file. In the worst case, you'll have to keep the information stored elsewhere.

Comment: I edited the first post, saying that the projects would be plugins for Moodle.
I guess that the most sensible information you can store in a build file would be IP directions (I've never used build systems, as I supposed you already deduced), am I wrong?

Comment: I guess you mean [moodle](https://moodle.org/) - but I don't see "build system" being used for the plugins. Do you mean the install.xml you should provide?